# mysql wildcards % vs %%

Tags: mysql, wildcard, where-clause

What is the difference in '%' and '%%', when used in mysql where clause with 'LIKE' ?

```
select * from `wp_users` u where u.user_nicename like "%lastuser%"
```

VS

```
select * from `wp_users` u where u.user_nicename like "%%lastuser%%"
```

Comment: Where did you see this used? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @Pekka: in buddypress core files ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference between `%%` and `%` when it comes to pattern matching in mysql.

I've seen developers get confused over this when they try to match a literal `%` and therefor write `%%`. This is most often because of the fact that [format-strings](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/software-dev/cheat-sheet-reference-printf-format-specifier-syntax) often use a double `%` to indicate that you'd like it to be treated as an exact literal.

---

#### MySQL documentation of `LIKE`

- [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 11.5.1 String Comparison Functions :: `LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

---

#### What's the origin of the string, and where is it going?

If the string is passed to a function such as [`sprintf`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) the format-string rule I mentioned earlier is present, though there is no confusion in that case.

The developer want it to be a single `%` in the string passed to mysql, and therefor wrote `%%`.

```
$query = sprintf (
  "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id <> %d AND data LIKE '%%hello world%%'",
  50
);

// $query => "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id <> 50 AND data LIKE '%hello world%'";
```

---

#### A few sample SELECTs using the LIKE operator

```
mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ab%';
+------------------+
| 'abc' LIKE 'ab%' |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ab%%';
+-------------------+
| 'abc' LIKE 'ab%%' |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ab\%';
+-------------------+
| 'abc' LIKE 'ab\%' |
+-------------------+
|                 0 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 'ab%' LIKE 'ab\%';
+-------------------+
| 'ab%' LIKE 'ab\%' |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```