# What do %% and % in these queries mean?

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following 2 Python codes:

```
def direct_by_node(self, node, partition_size):
    return '''select req.id, req.profile_id as profile
                  from table1 attr
                  where id % {0} = {1}'''.format(partition_size, node)
```

and then

```
def find_by_node(self, node, partition_size):
    return '''select req.id, req.profile_id as profile
                  from table1 attr
                  where id %% {0} = {1}'''.format(partition_size, node)
```

I am wondering what % and %% in the 2 MySQL queries are about?

**Edit:**

When I try %% in MySQL Workbench, looks like I have a syntax error, looks like %% is invalid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616880/8106112

Comment: thanks @darnell, i have seen this one, but I am not entirely sure it's the same to mine as the one is something like "%lastuser%"...

Comment: Don't use Python string formatting to generate a SQL query string; use your library's ability to create parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a Modulo operation and calculates the remainder of id divided by partition_size then compare it with node.

Look at a simple example here:

```
mysql> SELECT 253 % 7;
    -> 1 # because 253 = 36*7 + 1
```

[More function_mod examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

As you noticed %% is not a valid operator.