# How does mysql handle multiple % symbols next to each other

Tags: mysql

Does mysql combine multiple % symbols together?

1. ada%%m
2. ada%m

When I search a column for #1, does that get treated like #2, or does #1 take additional search power?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql wildcards % vs %%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616829/mysql-wildcards-vs)

Comment: My question isn't how does it function (which your link states). My question is about impact on the server - when your searching larger data sets

Comment: The first line of the accepted answer does state there is no difference between the two though

Comment: Please read your links: "There is no difference between %% and % when it comes to pattern matching"

Comment: No difference between the two somewhat implies same performance. Meanwhile, you could also answer this by yourself, simply make a bunch of queries using #1, then a bunch of queries using #2, and compare benchmarks.

Comment: Proof? I won't respond again because you are more concerned with being right