# mysql LIKE with double percent

Tags: php, mysql, yii, sql-like

I just debugging a legacy code and I found a strange part in it. Does anybody has an idea, what does the following mean in the MYSQL string?

```
full_name LIKE '%%{fullname}%%'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616829/mysql-wildcards-vs

Comment: Can you show more context of this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the answer Mihir Dave's comment links to, there's no difference to SQL if you pass `%%` instead of `%`. Since a single `%` matches zero or more characters, then each of the metacharacters in `%%` would also match zero or more, and ultimately the same string would match one way or another.

But I'd guess your legacy code is pre-Python 2.6 that uses `%` as a metacharacter in string formatting, and you have to double it like `%%` to get a single literal `%` character.

See also:

- [How can I selectively escape percent (%) in Python strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings)
- https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Comment: Forget it to mention, the environment is Yii1/PHP. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used Yii. Is it possible it's using `%{fullname}%` as a token to replace with some content, and then the extra `%` characters on either side are the actual SQL wildcards?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it is a legacy issue. I have used double percent in python 3.7 as well, though admittedly on an older mysql version, with double percent having the only function of escaping the second %.
I came to this by [Python3.8, MySQL5.7: passing active wildcards to LIKE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004189/python3-8-mysql5-7-passing-active-wildcards-to-like-query/63004314#63004314)