# Python3.8, MySQL5.7: passing active wildcards to LIKE query

Tags: python-3.8, mysql-connector-python

I am using python3.8 and mysql.connector.  Can I parameterize a query that contains a `LIKE` clause and pass in active `%` wildcard(s)?

To tame the incoming pattern I have tried:

```
pattern = re.sub(r'%+', '%', target)
~and~
pattern = re.sub(r'%+', '%%', target)
~and~
pattern = re.sub(r'%+', '\\%', target)
```

for the queries I have tried:

```
cursor.execute(f"""
    DELETE FROM thnigs
    WHERE user =  %(user)s
        AND widget LIKE %(pattern)s
""", dict(user=username, pattern=pattern))

cursor.execute(f"""
    DELETE FROM thnigs
    WHERE user =  %s
        AND widget LIKE %s
""", (username, pattern))
```

`pattern` could contain just about anything really.  I know that mysql.connector will escape the input but if the input string contains any number of percent symbols the query hangs then dies with: `1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

I have tried switching the `LIKES` for `RLIKES` aand changing the wildcards to simple `.*` strings with the same result -- if there is any active wildcard then the query dies.

Values that have not worked so far:

```
pattern = "%red"
pattern = "red%"
```

If this is not possible then I suppose I could pull in all values and do the wildcard search locally in the app but that feels wrong.  The possible dataset could potentially become large.

Is there a correct or better way?

** Edit **
added another `%` replacement pattern that i have tried

Answer (score 0):

You must escape % with %% in the sql query text that is passed, this is what I remember at least from long ago.

See also

[mysql LIKE with double percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863249/mysql-like-with-double-percent/63004371#63004371)

and there my answer.

Comment: Yep, tried that too.  If I manage to get one or more %s in the string the query does.

Comment: @7Reeds Meaning it works now? Or do you mean you tried, but that did not solve it in the end? Just to make sure I understand your comment.

Comment: just went back to check.  If my initial string is "%red"  or "red%" and the percent signs are doubled then it works, thank you.  If the initial string is "%red%" and the percents are doubled to "%%red%%" then it throws the exception above.

Comment: I got RLIKE to work.  never did find the magic for regular LIKE and the `%`s. Cheers

Comment: @7Reeds Then this cannot be called completely solved, perhaps someone else will contribute. It could be a duplicate anyway, I had the same issue a year ago and I got it to work with the help of then existing SO threads. If it is not a duplicate, your question will get more attendance anyway.