# Passing variable into mysql 8 select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, select

I am trying a simple select statement with a variable. The statement works fine if I change the like concat_ws('%', @S, '%'); to a string. It seems that the select statement is not picking up the SET variable. Help would be much appreciated. I am using Mysql80 workbench.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
SET @S = "product";
SELECT distinct idproducts FROM mgjtest.vorutaflamedsamheit
WHERE productname like concat_ws('%', @S, '%');
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to ensure wildcards on either side of variable value. Otherwise, [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) which uses first argument as separator returns double wildcards at the end of string which is [equivalent to single wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8616829/1422451) and yields undesired results.

```sql
LIKE 'product%%'

LIKE 'product%'
```

However, `CONCAT` will return wildcards as you expect:

```sql
LIKE '%product%'
```